# Open port in apartment network

Tags: port

everyone,
I'm living in a apartment an using a network with private IP.
In this network, BitTorrent is work correctly and can seeds data.
The question is,
can I open 80?
Thanks for help.

Comment: You mean open port 80 from the Internet to your Lan ? yes it is. You probably have a router to get internet access. You will have to set it up to forward incoming requests from `your_public_ip:80` to `your_private_ip:80`

Comment: Who controls the router? Is it you?

Comment: @MariusMatutiae I have a router in my house and there is a router owned by my apartment. I thinks my port can be my opened because p2p is working.

Comment: If you control the router, you can open any port and forward it to any pc you wish.

Comment: @MariusMatutiae I can't control the outside router.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a difference between accessing an outside service, and providing a service for the outside world.

As a manager of a router, I can prevent or allow either, both, neither.

As a user, without control of the router, I am at the mercy of the router owner.

So, the fact that you can access http service (port 80) on an outside server, does not imply that you can create such service (a Web server) locally, and allow other people from outside your local network to reach it. This requires port forwarding, something that can only be done from within the router.

The parallel with torrent is not apt: what your router allows is your use of an outside service, not the creation of a torrent service on your local pcs. Same thing as port 80.